# What's the exact rule of applying a theorem in Coq?

Tags: coq

I'm studying the SoftwareFoundation at https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/lf-current/toc.html. The section Logic states that theorem can be used just like a function. I tried some examples but failed to get common rules.

The first try:

```
Example xxx:
  (0 = 2) -> (0 = 3).
Proof. Admitted.
Example yyy:
  (0 = 2) -> (0 = 3).
Proof.
  intros H.
  apply (xxx H). (* this works *)
  apply (xxx (0 = 2)). (* this fails. *)
Qed.
```

Coq give me an error on failed version as below. Except that it fails, I still cannot understand why is strange type `0 = 2` required instead of `Prop` ?

```
The term "0 = 2" has type "Prop" while it is expected to have type "0 = 2".
```

If I use relation `<->` in `xxx` instead of `->`, `(xxx H)` fails either...

```
Example xxx:
  (0 = 2) <-> (0 = 3).
Proof. Admitted.
Example yyy:
  (0 = 2) -> (0 = 3).
Proof.
  intros H.
  apply (xxx H). (* this fails either *)
Qed.
```

The most important, SF shows how to apply a Theorem in Lemma `lemma_application_ex` (the below example), I have totally no idea about how does `(proj1 _ _ (In_map_iff _ _ _ _ _) H)` work ...

```
Lemma proj1 : forall P Q : Prop,
  P /\ Q -> P.
Proof.
  intros P Q [HP HQ].
  apply HP.  Qed.

Lemma In_map_iff :
  forall (A B : Type) (f : A -> B) (l : list A) (y : B),
    In y (map f l) <->
    exists x, f x = y /\ In x l.
Proof.
  (* FILL IN HERE *) Admitted.

Example lemma_application_ex :
  forall {n : nat} {ns : list nat},
    In n (map (fun m => m * 0) ns) ->
    n = 0.
Proof.
  intros n ns H.
  destruct (proj1 _ _ (In_map_iff _ _ _ _ _) H)
           as [m [Hm _]]. (* I cannot understand this application *)
  rewrite mult_0_r in Hm. rewrite <- Hm. reflexivity.
Qed.
```

Comment: Just added more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in that chapter, the type of a theorem or lemma is the statement that it proves.  For instance,

```
Check xxx.
(* 0 = 2 -> 0 = 3 *)
```

The same holds for hypotheses when you are proving a theorem:

```
Example yyy:
  (0 = 2) -> (0 = 3).
Proof.
  intros H.
  Check H. (* 0 = 2 *)
```

The first error message you saw says that you need to pass the *proof of a proposition* as an argument, rather than the proposition itself.  The type of `0 = 2` is `Prop`, not `0 = 2` itself. Similarly, when you use the `plus` function, the argument must be of type `nat`, but `nat` itself won't work:

```
Check plus 1 2. (* nat *)
Check plus nat nat.
(* Error: The term "nat" has type "Set"
   while it is expected to have type "nat". *)
```

**Edit**

Note that the application syntax only works for implication statements and universal quantification.  You get an error when using a theorem of type `A <-> B` in this way because this statement means `(A -> B) /\ (B -> A)`, which doesn't fall into these cases. *However*, you can use the `proj1 : forall A B, A /\ B -> A` lemma to extract the first side of the equivalence and apply it to something.  For instance, we could fill in the implicit arguments of `proj1 _ _ ...` in the example you mentioned:

```
proj1 (In n (map (fun m => m * 0) ns))
      (exists x, (fun m => m * 0) x = n)
      (In_map_iff nat nat (fun m => m * 0) ns n)
      H
```

If we remove the `H` part, this application has type

```
In n (map (fun m => m * 0) ns) ->
exists x, (fun m => m * 0) x = n
```

which can be applied to `H : In n (map .. ns)` to get a proof of an existential statement.

Comment: Stack Overflow does not encourage irrelevant discussion or reply, but I still want to say, thanks a lot, it solved my confusion : ).

Answer (score 0):

To understand `(proj1 _ _ (In_map_iff _ _ _ _ _) H)`, you can use `Check` to analyze it step by step:

- `Check proj1.`

  ```
  : forall P Q : Prop, P /\ Q -> P
  ```
- `Check proj1 _ _.`

  ```
  : ?P /\ ?Q -> ?P
  ```
- `Check In_map_iff.`

  ```
  : forall (A B : Type) (f : A -> B) 
      (l : list A) (y : B),
    In y (map f l) <->
    (exists x : A, f x = y /\ In x l)
  ```
- `Check In_map_iff _ _ _ _ _.`

  ```
  : In ?y (map ?f ?l) <->
   (exists x : ?A, ?f x = ?y /\ In x ?l)
  ```
- `Check @proj1 _ _ (In_map_iff _ _ _ _ _).`

  ```
  : In ?y (map ?f ?l) ->
   exists x : ?A, ?f x = ?y /\ In x ?l
  ```
- `Check proj1 _ _ (In_map_iff _ _ _ _ _) H.`

  ```
  : exists x : nat, x * 0 = n /\ In x ns
  ```